# How to have an Infopath form lookup sharepoint list data based on textbox input

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I want to build a form which looks up an asset based on its serial number.
I already have the list of assets built in SharePoint with ID, Serial Number and Asset columns.

The Asset name and Serial Number display in a repeating section linked and I want to be able to filter the entries displayed by typing a serial number into a text box.

I have successfully created the repeating table so that it displays the correct data but I am failing to create the filter can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create a Data Connection that pulls the data from the Assets List. 
Add a filter that will get the data for the particular Asset Id and then bind it to the repeating table.
Once that is done, go to the repeating table and bind the `Data Fields` from the Data connection to the text boxes in the repeating table.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a rule on the Serial Number text box. The rule has the action of querying the List of Assets based on the serial number. Then after the querying, set the Asset column with the value of Asset on you Asset List Data Connection.