# Query data from SharePoint list

Tags: infopath, lookup-column

I have an "Employee" list which contains username and employee no. and there is another list which contains a column that lookups employee no. in Employee list.

The issue is that I want to show only that employee no. in lookup field where username is equal to current username.

How can I do it using Infopath?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can add filters or writes rules

Comment: Can you please update the question by adding screen shots of both lists

Answer (score 1):

1. Create data connection to source list in infopath form
2. change column to calculated
3. Select filed where you want to display employee number
4. To add value in column, click on fx, then select source list data connection
5. Add filer, like **ABC** then show **Employee ID**

Here are some [articles](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/get-infopath-to-display-lookup-column-value-not-id/)

[article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/161229/how-to-have-an-infopath-form-lookup-sharepoint-list-data-based-on-textbox-input)